# How to load an AnchorPane in a SplitPane that existed in another SplitPane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I created a horizontal split pane then I created a vertical one.

How to load an anchorPane in the second split pane?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you add any other Node in a SplitPane or you added your second SplitPane to the first one.

```
verticalOne.getItems().add(anchorPane);
```

Comment: how can I get the the vertical one.

Comment: how did you create it?

Comment: How can I get the the vertical one? (When I created the horizontal I get 2 AnchorPane in the second, I create the second SplitPane)

Comment: Please post the peace of code in your question where you do that!

Comment: I create it using Scene builder

Comment: so you are using fxml files. You need to give the Nodes fx:id="" attributes. then in your class you can load them by adding an @FXML tag to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

my fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.1927710843373494" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="558.0" prefWidth="1100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" stylesheets="@projet/Demo.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <items>
    <AnchorPane id="anchor1" disable="true" maxHeight="120.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="160.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="104.0" fitWidth="1100.0" opacity="0.34" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@projet/Sans%20tre.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="919.0" layoutY="8.0" text="RABT LE 04/12/2014" textFill="BLUE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children></AnchorPane>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
         <children>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.17883211678832117" layoutY="-9.0" prefHeight="446.0" prefWidth="1098.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane id="anchor2" maxWidth="200.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="424.0" prefWidth="180.0">
                     <children>
                        <VBox layoutX="6.0" layoutY="30.0" maxHeight="335.0" maxWidth="175.0" minHeight="315.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="424.0" prefWidth="152.0" snapToPixel="false" spacing="30.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button layoutX="34.0" layoutY="47.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Saisir les données" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="34.0" layoutY="90.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Consulter les&#10; informations&#10; des intervention " textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Consulter les&#10;Statistiques" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <VBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                                 </VBox.margin>
                              </Button>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane id="anchor3" disable="true" maxWidth="30000.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="889.0" prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="901.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" />
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: change id to fx:id when you load this fxml in your java class you get these Nodes: @FXML AnchorPane anchor2;